# How to transform the following query in Mongo using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I can run it in Robomongo, but I do not know how to do this in C #

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
     {$match : { "Partner._id": {$in: ["acb123","def456"]}}}, 
     {$group : {_id: {status: "$Status"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

Comment: Next time please show what you have tried by posting the non-working code which you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fluent aggregation and simply parse BsonDocuments from JSON strings:

```
var result = await mycollection.Aggregate()
       .Match(BsonDocument.Parse("{ 'Partner._id': {$in: ['acb123','def456']} }"))
       .Group(BsonDocument.Parse("{ _id: '$Status', count: {$sum: 1} }"))
       .ToListAsync();
```

Or you can build BsonDocuments manually:

```
var result = await mycollection.Aggregate()
   .Match(
      new BsonDocument {
         {"Partner._id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(new []{"acb123","def456"}))}
      }
   ).Group(
      new BsonDocument {
         { "_id", "$Status" },  // thus you group by single field
         { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) }
      }
   ).ToListAsync();
```